# Asp.net MVC 3 Website Loading Failed from server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have developed an asp.net MVC 3 website. When I upload the site to a server (bin folder in which there are dll files) and Views (in which there all necessary pages) and other folders except coding and also upload the web.config file.

But when I enter a URL in web browser it give me the error:

> Server Error in '/' Application. The system cannot find the file
>   specified

Kindly inform me how to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what does the FULL error say?

Comment: Did you do a Publish or just copied the mentioned files?